# Can be solved without L'Hopital?

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals, limits-without-lhopital

Can this limit be evaluated without l'hopital's rule?

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{8+h}-2}{h}$$

Comment: sure, the 3rd square root is differentiable in 8. And your expression is (assuming $h\to 0$) just a difference quotient

Comment: It probably should be $h \to 0$ in the limit.

Comment: @Rogers mixedmath's solution is actually the simplest and most intuitive. Try to work it out based off the hint.

Comment: l'Hopital's rule can actually be derived from other rules; it is not an "axiom." So if a limit can be solved with l'Hopital's rule, it can also be solved without l'Hopital's rule.

Comment: @BenMillwood Agh! Sorry, made a typo, comment now corrected.

Comment: Although the answer has been accepted, a further hint (maybe) based on @TylerHolden comment:
$$\frac{(8+h)^{1/3}-2}{h}=\frac{(1+h/8)^{1/3}-1}{h/2}$$
since $h\to0$, some expression can be extrapolated with asymptotics...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)\implies x-y=\frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2+xy+y2}$$

Now we put

$$x=\sqrt[3]{8+h}\;,\;\;y=2\implies \sqrt[3]{8+h}-2=\frac{8+h-8}{(8+y)^{2/3}+2\sqrt[3]{8+h}+4}\implies$$

$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{8+h}-2}h=\frac1{(8+h)^{2/3}+2\sqrt[3]{8+h}+4}\xrightarrow[h\to 0]{}\frac1{8^{2/3}+2\sqrt[3]8+4}=\ldots$$

Comment: Some net lag I just had, I didn't see your answer or Yiorgos' before I posted. No sense in having 3 identical answers. (+1)

Answer (score 27):

Try to let: $u= (8 + h)^{1/3} $

Thus $u^3 = 8 + h$

$h = u^3 - 8$

Then the limit becomes:

$$\lim_{u\to2}\frac{u-2}{u^3-8} = \lim_{u\to2}\frac{u-2}{(u-2)(u^2+2u+4)}=\lim_{u\to2}\frac{1}{u^2+2u+4}$$

Comment: This seems to be the same basic idea as DonAntonio, but it is expressed much more simply and clearly. +1

Comment: Haha wow, I don't go on the computer for 2 days and I see this. Thanks everyone! :)

Comment: This indeed is the same idea as in my answer but seriously simpler and nicer. I can't understand how come my answer was  accepted and not this one. Anyway, +1

Answer (score 11):

**HINT**:

Think about the definition of a derivative, recognize this expression as the derivative of something. (*And yes, this can be found without l'Hopital's rule*).

Answer (score 5):

One neat way to solve some limits is to use [Taylor series](http://planetmath.org/exampleofcomputinglimitsusingtaylorexpansion).  If you recall the Maclaurin expansion
$$(1 + x)^n = 1 + nx + \mathcal{O}(x^2)$$
you can see that
$$\sqrt[3]{8 + h} -2 = 2\sqrt[3]{1 + h/8} -2 \approx 2\left(1 + \frac{h}{24}\right) -2 = \frac{h}{12}$$
so the limit becomes
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h/12}{h} = \frac{1}{12}.$$

Comment: It's a neat way to solve *a lot* of limits, I have never touched L'Hopital & co. since I knew Taylor expansions and small-oh notation.

Comment: @MatteoItalia it's the same for me.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt[3]{8+h}-2}{h}&=
\frac{\sqrt[3]{(8+h)^2}+2\sqrt[3]{8+h}+4}{\sqrt[3]{(8+h)^2}+2\sqrt[3]{8+h}+4}
\cdot \frac{\sqrt[3]{8+h}-2}{h} \\&=\frac{(8+h)-8}{h}
\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(8+h)^2}+2\sqrt[3]{8+h}+4}
\to\frac{1}{12}.
\end{align}